# jscrollpane arrow button

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using jscrollpane with arrows (only scrolling vertically). I have two buttons on my page and I want those buttons to work the same way the scroll arrow vertical buttons (up and down) are working.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ (download link)

Comment: for scrolling up - $('.jScrollArrowUp').trigger('mousedown');
$('html').trigger('mouseup'); for scrolling down - $('.jScrollArrowDown').trigger('mousedown');
   $('html').trigger('mouseup');

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jScrollPane API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) and the scrollBy method to accomplish this. I have put together an example on jsfiddle.net:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/gLRYu/2/

The code from my example looks like this (and relies on ids of "scroll-up" and "scroll-down" being added to the links on the page):

```
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
$('#scroll-up').bind(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        api.scrollByY(-10);
        return false;
    }
);
$('#scroll-down').bind(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        api.scrollByY(10);
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: The jsfiddle link above works fine for me... What browser are you seeing an error on? Do you have errors on my example pages or just on the page you are developing?